# Method App\Follower::__toString() must not throw an exception: Error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am making a follower user controller in laravel.

My controller has the following function:

```
public function follow($id)
{
    if (Auth::user()) {
        $follower = Auth::user()->user_id;
        $user_to_follow = User::Find($id);
        if ($user_to_follow) {
            $follower = new Follower;
            $follower->follower_id = $follower;
            $follower->user_id = $user_to_follow;
            if ($follower->save()) {           <-- receiving error here
                return "done";
            } else {
                return redirect('/')->back();
            }
        }
        return $follower;
    } 
}
```

**Follower** Model:

```
 protected $table = "followers";

protected $fillable = ['follower_id', 'user_id', 'accepted'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

**User** Model

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Follower', 'user_id');
}
```

And in View

```
<a href="/follow/2">Follow</a>
```

On Clicking Follow I receive error,

> Method App\Follower::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\JsonEncodingException: Error encoding
>   model [App\Follower] with ID [] to JSON: Recursion detected

Can Someone explain What this error is and how to remove this?
Thank you in advance..

Comment: Can you show your full model definitions, just to make sure there's nothing else hiding in there?

Comment: @aynber Follower model has just that...  and user model has relation with other models and  protected $table = "users";

    protected $primaryKey = "user_id";

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_name', 'email', 'password', 'tag_id',
    ];

   
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is quite obvious, you are using same variable for 2 different things. First you do:

```
$follower = Auth::user()->user_id;
```

but later you do

```
$follower = new Follower;
```

so now when you use:

```
$follower->follower_id = $follower;
```

then you try assign same object to object property and probably it causing problem when saving.

What you should do is changing:

```
$follower = Auth::user()->user_id;
```

into

```
$followerId = Auth::user()->user_id;
```

and then

```
$follower->follower_id = $follower;
```

into

```
$follower->follower_id = $followerId;
```

Comment: Lol yeah... I didn't realized that. What a silly error, I have been banging my head into. Thankyou for help